# Test NestJs API controller with Jest

Tags: api, jestjs, nestjs

I am creating an API with NestJs and mysql.
My controller function for create a new entity is working well, however, I can't test the usecase where the response is a 400 error.

This is the controller function :

```js
@Controller('pubs')
export class PubsController {
   constructor(private readonly pubsService: PubsService) {}
   @Post()
   async create(@Body() createPubDto: CreatePubDto, @Res() res: Response): Promise<void> {
     this.pubsService.create(createPubDto)
       .then(() => res.status(201).json())
       .catch(err => res.status(401).json({ err }));
   }
}
```

And this is the test file :

```js
describe('PubsController', () => {
  let controller: PubsController;
  let service: PubsService;
  const mockResponse = () => {
    const res: any = {};
    res.status = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(res);
    res.json = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(res);
    return res;
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [PubsController],
      providers: [PubsService, {
        provide: getRepositoryToken(Pub),
        useValue: {},
      }],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<PubsController>(PubsController);
    service = module.get<PubsService>(PubsService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  describe('create success', () => {
    const res = mockResponse();
    it('Should create a pub', async () => {
      const req = mockedPub;
      jest.spyOn(service, 'create').mockResolvedValue(mockedPub);
      await controller.create(req, res);
      expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(201);
    });
    it('Should return 400 if the body is not correct', async () => {
      const req: any = {};
      jest.spyOn(service, 'create').mockResolvedValue(req);
      await controller.create(req, res);
      expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(400);
    });
  }) 
});
```

"Should create a pub" is working well, but when I give to the create function an empty object, the test give me a 201 res.status.

```js
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: 400
    Received: 201
```

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

First, do you use any validation pipe anywhere in your code in order to validate the incoming `CreatePubDto`, e.g. in your `main.ts` file or in the `pubService` ?

Second, in your test that should fail, you have written `jest.spyOn(service, 'create').mockResolvedValue(req);` which resolves, and thus you won't catch any error at the controller level, which means you go in the `.then(() => res.status(201).json())` of your controller logic.

You should refactor the test to:

```js
it('Should return 400 if the body is not correct', async () => {
    const error: any = { message: 'bad DTO provided', code: 400 }; // <== this is where you mock the logic of your service to throw an error
    jest.spyOn(service, 'create').mockRejectedValue(error);
    await controller.create(req, res);
    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(400);
});
```

This way you're telling Jest to throw an error when the `create` method is called. I put example error that could be thrown, but feel free to use your own error format that will be thrown.

Also don't forget to align your error code returned in your controller with the one expected in your test. `400` would be the more appropriate I guess in this use case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and the welcome :) ).

I don'ty use any validation pipe for the createPubDto.
It's the controller function which catch if the Pub send is not a good one.

here is the function create of the service :
`create(pub: Pub): Promise<Pub> {
        return this.PubsRepository.save(pub);
      }`

With the change you preconize, I have the following error :
`expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: 400

    Number of calls: 0`

Does that mean that I have to move the 'then - catch' in the service function ?